# MultipleSelect from library react-select-material-ui not working in IE11 or lower

Tags: reactjs

I am using MultipleSelect from library 'react-select-material-ui'. It seems to work fine in all modern browser such as chrome, mozilla, Safari but for Internet explorer version 11 it is throwing error.

**SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'root' of undefined or null reference
0.chunk.js (230075,7)**

Although the demo [link](https://iulian-radu-at.github.io/react-select-material-ui/?path=/story/reactselectmaterialui--allowing-creating-new-options) for multiple select with creating new options seems to work fine in IE11

Here is below code options variable is returning data and I have changeMenu method initialized.

```
<MultipleSelect
                        label="Choose or add menus"
                        values={options}
                        options={options}
                        onChange={this.changeMenu}
                        SelectProps={{
                          isCreatable: true,
                        }}
                      />
```

Any help will be highly appreciated